Asymptotic proportion of integers with at least $k$ prime factors
There is significant discussion here about the asymptotics of $$\pi_k(x):=\{y<x|y=p_1....p_k\}$$
the number of integers less than $x$ with precisely $k$ distinct prime factors. For example, we get the relation
$$\pi_k(x)\sim x\frac{\log^{k-1}\log (x)}{\log(x) (k-1)!}$$
Now define $\Pi_k(x):=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \pi_n(x)$, the number of integers less than $x$ with at least $k$ distinct prime factors.
Question: Are there results on the asymptotics of $\Pi_k(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$?

The sum of the asymptotics would definitely not work since it is valid for small values of $k$, whereas in your case $k\to+\infty$.

Note that $$\Pi_{k}\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\pi_{n}\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\pi_{n}\left(x\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\pi_{n}\left(x\right)=Q\left(x\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\pi_{n}\left(x\right)$$ where $Q\left(x\right):=#\left{ y\le x:y;\mathrm{is;square-free}\right} $. If k is fixed, you can use the above asymptotic. Also, $Q\left(x\right)\sim\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}x$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.
